# Convert Time and Date in string to date VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, string-to-datetime

I'm using RSS feeds from multiple sources and I'm sorting the feeds by date. However, the dates I receive are in different time zones.

This is the format of some of the date strings that I get:

Wed 08 Dec 2021 01:40:31 -0500
Wed 08 Dec 2021 11:11:19 -0600

The "-500' indicates the time zone which is UTC-5. I need to use that "-0500" to convert this string into a date and the date needs to be only in UTC.

Basically from "Wed 08 Dec 2021 01:40:31 -0500"  to  "12/08/2021 06:40:31"

I've managed to split the string up to sort by date but because of the time difference, it doesn't really help.

Is there coding which I can use to convert the string as-is into date and only UTC time? Or is there just a place where I can start?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact), you specify a format to convert from, and that can include "zzz" for the timezone offset. You can also specify that you want the result in UTC:

```
Dim s = "Wed 08 Dec 2021 01:40:31 -0500"
Dim d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddd dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
Console.WriteLine(d.Kind.ToString())
```

Outputs:

> 2021-12-08 06:40:31
> Utc

Of course, format the result as you desire.

Alternatively, if you need to, you can keep the offset by using a DateTimeOffset structure and adjust it to UTC for representation as a string:

```
Dim s = "Wed 08 Dec 2021 01:40:31 -0500"
Dim d = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "ddd dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Nothing)

Console.WriteLine(d.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Outputs:

> 2021-12-08 06:40:31

Comment: Beautiful, thank you it works perfectly.