# How to parse String to DateTime using ParseExact

Tags: string, vb.net, datetime, parsing

So i have a problem parsing a string to date in order to format it.

i tried doing it like that :

`(DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionItem.Headers("DateRecieved"), "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", new CultureInfo("en-US"))).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

but the error comes from this part
`DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionItem.Headers("DateRecieved"), "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", new CultureInfo("en-US"))`

where TransactionItem is a MailMessage object.
I'm trying to get it's "recieved on" date which appears to be a string looking like that : "Tue, 18 May 2021 11:17:21 +0200" and format it to look like that "18/05/2021 09:17:21"

looked up other posts and solutions and somehow nothing works always an exception maybe my mask is off or something idk, any ideas?

Comment: You don't specify the error message but at first glance you are spelling 'received' incorrectly.

Comment: Please see my answer to [Convert Time and Date in string to date VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274662/1115360) and add a comma after the "ddd".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [Convert Time and Date in string to date VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274461/convert-time-and-date-in-string-to-date-vb-net).