# How do I parse PDF Iso Date?

Tags: vb.net, pdf

Using iText7 and documentinfo.GetMoreInfo("ModDate"), I get the following date string:

D:20220817113241+00'00'

How do I parse this in VB.NET?

Comment: I think you would have to do a tiny bit of post-processing on the offset, and otherwise it should be straightforward to compose a format string to parse this using `DateTime.ParseExact` (there isn't a format string for the minutes offset, and the full offset string appears to expect what I assume to be the locale-based separator).  Did you try looking in the docs before asking here?

Comment: If you tidy up that example string to `"20220817113241+00:00"`, you can use `Dim yourDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", Nothing)` where `s` contains the tidied string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think you need ff after the ss as there are hundredths of a second if I'm counting right.

Comment: Also, this feels like something that should be a duplicate, but I'm not sure there is one that's a great match.  Nearest I found with a search for ParseExact was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274461/convert-time-and-date-in-string-to-date-vb-net

Comment: @Craig I copied that straight from a working test - there aren't any fractions of a second - it's 2022-08-17 11:32:41.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i.e. I did not, in fact, count correctly. :-)

Comment: @KJ What do you mean by "shift 4", please?

Comment: @AndrewMorton What do you mean by "tidy up"? I have removed the trailing "D:", but it throws a System.FormatExpection error when I use ""20220821165805+02'00'"".

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments, I found a solution:

Initial date string:

```
D:20220817113241+00'00'
```

If string starts with "D:", remove it.

```
20220817113241+00'00'
```

If a string has a +, remove the part beginning with the +.

```
20220817113241
```

Use a full format string like this:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz
```

Now measure the length of the remaining date string.

For example:

```
        Dim s As String = "D:20220817113241+00'00'"

        Dim sFormat As String = "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz"
        Dim iLen As Integer = s.Length

        sFormat = Mid(sFormat, 0, iLen)

        This makes the format string as long as the date string and cuts off anything that is not present in the date string, like "zzz".
```

Now use that format string like this:

```
Dim yourDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, sFormat, Nothing)
```

Comment: @KJ Do you perhaps have a link to documentation for a "D: string"?

Comment: @KJ Thanks! It looks like the PDF standard should say "PDF defines a *non-standard* date format..."! Especially as it post-dates ISO 8601. Oh well, too late to change it now I suppose.